# OpenLayers4 / JavaScript : Feature type '****' is not available error

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to save a polygon that I have draw on a vector layer. The following code snippet is giving me an error
code:

```
var node;
        var lName = 'workspacename:layername, http://*.*.*.*:8080/geoserver';
        var layerAuth = "-";
        var lNameInfo = lName.split(',');
        var url = lNameInfo[1];
        var layer = lNameInfo[0];
        //console.log(layer.split(':')[0]);
        var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
        var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({           
            featureNS: url + '/' + layer.split(':')[0],
            featureType: layer.split(':')[1],
            srsName: 'EPSG:28191'
        });
```

the error:

```
Feature type 'PROPBLG' is not available:
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GML-GML.html), the `featureType` should also contain the namespace.

Try with `featureType: layer,`